# How to pass arrays to a smart contract function from frontend using react and ethers js?

Tags: ethers.js, react

What is the approach to take an array as input from the user on frontend and then storing it in useState and pass it to a smart contract  using ethers. I am just unable to create the correct format.
Using react for frontend.

This is the function I wanna call.

```
   // SPDX-License-Identifier: SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./MultiSig.sol";

contract ZarFactory {
    event Created(MultiSig walletAddress, address creator);

    function createWallet(address[] memory _owners, uint requiredSignature) external {
        MultiSig wallet = new MultiSig(_owners,requiredSignature);

        emit Created(wallet, msg.sender);
    }
}
```

Comment: An array of what exactly? Providing some snippets of what code you have would be helpful.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: The contract is fine.
I am not a frontend dev that's why unable to take correct input from the frontend and pass it to the contract.

Answer (score 0):

To pass an array to smart contract function from your React component, you can use the `ethers.utils.arrayify` function to convert the array to a format that can be passed to the smart contract

Here's a simple example

```
const values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const valuesBytes = ethers.utils.arrayify(values);

setValues(valuesBytes);
```

After setting the state in react component you can pass that array to the smart contract

Comment: Thanks I will try this.

Comment: It's not working 
This is the index js file ignore other functionalities just see the create wallet function and things related to it.
https://replit.com/@SolidityLearner/Multisig#pages/index.jsx

Comment: I'll have a look at updated question and update you shortly